# How to draw Sphere with OPENGL library?

Tags: opengl, geometry

Can somebody give full source code of drawing a sphere with OPENGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gluSphere(quadric,radius,slices,stacks);
```

[Source](http://www.talisman.org/opengl-1.1/Reference/gluSphere.html)

You need to have created the quadrics object with `gluNewQuadric`.